# obtener el nombre de usuario para mostrarlo una vez iniciada la sesion con php mysql html

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, session

tengo una cuestion con este codigo es que no me muesta el nombre del usuario, en si lo que pregunto es como se puede mostrar el nombre del usuario que inicio la sesion, y que aparesca en la esquina de la pagina web gracias de antemano

nota: cuando se inicia la sesion en la parte donde se deberia mostrar el nombre del usuario que inicio la sesion me muestra hola

este es el codigo que permite iniciar la sesion

```
    <?php //archivo para verfificar si existe usuario en la base de datos, es que verifica el login
session_start();
include 'conexionpadmi.php';

$usuarioestudiante= $_POST['usuarioestudianteform'];
$passwordestudiante=$_POST['passestudiante'];

$c= new OperacionesMysql();
$con=$c->Conectar();

$queryes = "SELECT * FROM tablaestudiante WHERE nombreestudiante='".$usuarioestudiante." ' AND pwestudiante= '".$passwordestudiante."'";

$qes= mysqli_query($con, $queryes);

if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($qes)) 
         {
            $resultpro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qes);

            echo 2;

            $_SESSION['login']='hola';
         }

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

y el codigo html aqui es donde se muestra el nombre del usuario obtenido en el codigo de arriba

```
<td id="idcelda1"  >
                <!--celda 1-->
                <label id="idnombreusuario">Nombre De Usuario:<?php echo '<h1 align=center>'.$_SESSION["login"].'</h1>'; ?> </label>
            </td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codijo ajax para ejecutar el login

```
$('#botonokestudiante').click(function(){
      var datos=$('#formestudinte').serialize();

       if ($('#nombreestu').val().trim() === '') {
        modalnombrevacio();

        return false; 
      } 

      if ($('#contraseñaestu').val().trim() === '') {
        modalpassvacio();

        return false; 
      } 

       $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../modelos/verificaloginestudiante.php",
        data:datos,
        cache: "false",
        beforeSend:function(){
          $('#botonokestudiante').val("conectando...");
        },
        success:function(data){
          $('#botonokestudiante').val("ingresar");
          if(data == 2){
             Limpiar();
              $(location).attr('href','../vistas/paginaestudiante.php');

          }else{

            Limpiar();
          }


        }
      });



        return false;
    });
```

codigo html del formulario

```
<form id="formestudinte">
        <div id="r2" class="animated fadeIn">
        <input type="text" name="usuarioestudianteform" id="nombreestu" placeholder="Usuario"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="password" name="passestudiante" id="contraseñaestu" placeholder="Contraseña"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="submit" value="ingresar" name="ok" id="botonokestudiante">

        <button id="regresaropcionesestu">Inicio</button>

        </div>

        </form>
```

codigo completo del html de la pagina donde se muestra el nombre del usuario

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>principal</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recursos/css/estilopaginaestudiante.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recursos/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="j../recursos/js/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recursos/js/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../recursos/css/animate.css">

     <script src="../recursos/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
     <script src="../recursos/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../recursos/js/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>

    <script src="../recursos/js/jspaginaestudiante.js"></script>

    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#nivel1").load("niveles/nivel1.php"); 

      $("#nivel2").load("niveles/nivel2.php"); 

      $("#nivel3").load("niveles/nivel3.php"); 

      $("#nivel4").load("niveles/nivel4.php"); 

      $("#nivel5").load("niveles/nivel5.php"); 
    });
    </script> 

</head>
<body>

<div id="contenedor">

<div id="nivel1"></div>

<div id="nivel2"></div>

<div id="nivel3"></div>

<div id="nivel4"></div>

<div id="nivel5"></div>
    <!-- niveles -->
    <table id="tablecuerpo" >
        <tr>
            <td id="idcelda1"  >
                <!--celda 1-->
                <label id="idnombreusuario">Nombre De Usuario:<?php echo $_SESSION["login"]; ?> </label>
            </td>
            <td id="idcelda2">
                <!--celda 2-->
                <button id="idbotoncerrarsesion">Cerrar Session</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="idcelada3" colspan="2">

            <!--celda3-->

            <button id="idbotonnivel1" class="diseñobotonnivel">nivel 1</button>
            <button id="idbotonnivel2" class="diseñobotonnivel">nivel 2</button>
            <button id="idbotonnivel3" class="diseñobotonnivel">nivel 3</button>
            <button id="idbotonnivel4" class="diseñobotonnivel">nivel 4</button>
            <button id="idbotonnivel5" class="diseñobotonnivel">nivel 5</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</div>

<div id="imagenizquierda">
    <img src="../recursos/svg/fondo1.svg" id="fondoindex1">

    <img src="../recursos/svg/fondo2.svg" id="fondoindex2">

</div>


        <div id="modalcerrarsessionn" class="animated bounceIn" >
        <p id="parrafochequeavacio">Deseas Cerrar Session</p>
        <button type="button" id="botonclosemodalpaginaestudinte" class="btn btn-secondary">Si</button>
        <button type="button" id="closemodalcerrarsession" class="btn btn-secondary">Cerrar</button>
        </div>

</body>
</html>


    <?php
}else{
    echo "no puede iniciar session";
    header("Location: index.php");
}

 ?>
```

codigo html completo del login y donde estan los formularios

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
//unset($_SESSION['login']);
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    //echo "bienbenido session ".$_SESSION['login'];
}else{
    //echo "sin session";
}



 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>principal login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0,maximun-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recursos/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="j../recursos/js/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recursos/js/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
    <script src="../recursos/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../recursos/js/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>
    <script src="../recursos/js/controlesindex.js"></script>
    <script src="../recursos/js/jsquerylogin.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/codigojslogin.js" ></script>
    <link href="../recursos/css/estiloslogin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../recursos/css/animate.css">

</head>
<body>

<!--<img id="imagenfondobody" class="animated fadeIn" src="../recursos/svg/dibujo3.svg">-->

<div id="contenedor">

<div id="modalnombrevacio" class="animated bounceIn">
        <p id="parrafochequeavacio">Debes Agregar El Nombre</p>
        <input type="radio" name="radiomodalchequeavacio" id="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" >
        <label for="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" id="botonmodalchequeavacio"><p class="textologin" id="textobotonregistrar" onclick="cerrarmodalnombrevacio();"  >Cerrar</p></label>
        </div>

        <div id="modalpassvacio" class="animated bounceIn">
        <p id="parrafochequeavacio">Debes Agregar La Contraseña</p>
        <input type="radio" name="radiomodalchequeavacio" id="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" >
        <label for="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" id="botonmodalchequeavacio"><p class="textologin" id="textobotonregistrar" onclick="cerrarmodalpassvacio();"  >Cerrar</p></label>
        </div>

        <div id="modalusuarionoencontrado" class="animated bounceIn">
        <p id="parrafochequeavacio">Usuario No Existe</p>
        <input type="radio" name="radiomodalchequeavacio" id="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" >
        <label for="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" id="botonmodalchequeavacio"><p class="textologin" id="textobotonregistrar" onclick="cerrarmodalusuarionoencontrado();"  >Cerrar</p></label>
        </div>

        <div id="modalmodificausuario" class="animated bounceIn">
        <p id="parrafochequeavacio">Usuario Modificado Con Exito</p>
        <input type="radio" name="radiomodalchequeavacio" id="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" >
        <label for="pulsacerramodalchequeavacio" id="botonmodalchequeavacio"><p class="textologin" id="textobotonregistrar" onclick="cerrarmodalmodificausuario();"  >Cerrar</p></label>
        </div>

    <form id="formulario" method="post"  name="formalarioprincipal" onsubmit="return validardatosvacion()">

        <div id="zonalogin" class="animated fadeIn">


        <input type="radio" name="radiologinregistra" id="pulsalogin" >
    <label for="pulsalogin" id="iniciarseccionboton"><p class="textologin">Diseño de un software Educativo de la Asignatura castellano para el CEIS "MARIA VELASQUEZ DE ROJAS"</p></label>



        </div>
        <!--<p id="pnombre">Nombre:</p>-->
        <div id="r1" class="animated fadeIn">
        <input type="text" name="cedeulaform" id="nombre" placeholder="Cedula"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="password" name="pwprofesor" id="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="submit" value="ingresar" name="ok" id="botonok">

        <button id="recuperarcuentausuario" >Recuperar Cuenta</button>
        <button id="regresaropciones">Inicio</button>
        </div>
        </form>

        <form id="formestudinte" method="POST">
        <div id="r2" class="animated fadeIn">
        <input type="text" name="usuarioestudianteform" id="nombreestu" placeholder="Usuario"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="password" name="passestudiante" id="contraseñaestu" placeholder="Contraseña"  maxlength="10">

        <input type="submit" value="ingresar" name="ok" id="botonokestudiante">

        <button id="regresaropcionesestu">Inicio</button>

        </div>

        </form>

        <div id="seccionopciones" class="animated fadeIn">
            <button id="opcionprefe">Profesor</button>
            <button id="opcionestu">Estudiante</button>
        </div>

    <!--modal modifica administrador-->

    <!--<img id="fondo1" src="img/fondo1.png">-->

    <div id="imagenizquierda">
    <img src="../recursos/svg2/pruebafonfoindex22.svg" id="fondoindex1" style="position: absolute; right: 74%; bottom: -280%;width: 40vmax;height: 40vmax; z-index: -1;">

    <img src="../recursos/svg2/figura11.svg" id="figura1" style="position: absolute; right: -110%; bottom: -340%; width: 45vmax;
    height: 45vmax;" >

    <img src="../recursos/svg2/figuras2.svg" id="figura2" style="position: absolute; right: 122%; bottom: 58%; width: 20vmax;
    height: 20vmax;">
    <!--<img id="fondo1" src="img/img2.png">-->
    </div>


                         <div id="modaldivcuentaadministrador">
                    <!--cuenta administrador-->

                    <div>
                        <?php 
                        require_once '../modelos/conexionpadmi.php';

                        $c= new OperacionesMysql();
                        $conexion=$c->Conectar();
                            $sql= "SELECT * FROM tablaadministrador WHERE idadmi= 2";
                            $rs=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            //$row = mysqli_fecth_array($rs);

                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($rs);
                        ?>
                        <form  id="formadmii" method="POST">

                            <table cellpadding="10%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">    
                                        <label>Nombre Del Administrador:</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="text" class="diseñocajatext" name="nombreusuario" value="<?=$row["nombreadmi"]?>">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label>Contraseña Del Administrador:</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="text" class="diseñocajatext" name="passusuario" value="<?=$row["pwadmi"]?>">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="cerrarmadalmodificausuario" onclick="cerrarmodalmodificausuario();">Cancelar</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="updateadmi" id="idupdateadmi">Modificar</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>






                        </form>

                    </div>

                 </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por favor no agregues contenido a las respuestas de quienes te aportan, así no funciona la comunidad; las ediciones donde se agrega código relevante debe ser hecha por el propio usuario que responde

Comment: ha ok, no quise hacer eso es que en vez de editar mi pregunta edite la respuesta del usuario no me di cuenta, bueno no lo hare y dispulpe la cuestion

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Tienes varios errores en el código que presentas. Enumero los principales y paso a proponerte una solución:

- No puedes usar dos veces `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, cada vez que lo usas el puntero de datos se mueve.
- Cuando usas `mysqli_fetch_assoc` debes buscar el dato asociado por el nombre de la columna, algo como `$fila["columna"]`. De todos modos, vamos a desestimar, para este caso esta forma de obtener los datos, optando por otra más conveniente...
- Convendría que verifiques las variables del POST
- Convendría que apliques consultas preparadas, te pueden inyectar código peligroso si pasas los datos directamente a ejecución con `query`. Aquí he usado consultas preparadas, he escrito un `SELECT` explícito de la columna que se necesita y he usado `bind_result` para obtener el dato. Parece trabajoso, pero es el precio a pagar por la seguridad de los datos e incluso del mismo sistema. La inyección SQL es un peligro que no se debe nunca minimizar.
- He dado más *coherencia* al código, por ejemplo incluyendo el archivo sólo cuando esté seguro de que lo voy a necesitar. También, para ganar en *coherencia*  y en *claridad* he escrito todo al estilo orientado a objetos.

Este es el código. Lo he hecho sobre la marcha. Espero que no tenga errores. Si hay algún problema o no entiendes algo lo puedes decir en comentarios.

Espero te sirva.

### PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /*Vamo a evitar variable kilométricas*/
    $usr=  ( empty($_POST['usuarioestudianteform']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['usuarioestudianteform'];
    $pass= ( empty($_POST['passestudiante']) )        ? NULL : $_POST['passestudiante'];

    if ($usr && $pass){
        include 'conexionpadmi.php';
        $c= new OperacionesMysql();
        $con=$c->Conectar();
        $sql="SELECT nombreestudiante FROM tablaestudiante WHERE nombreestudiante=? AND pwestudiante=? LIMIT 1";
        if( $stmt = $con->prepare($sql) ){
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usr,$pass);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($nombre);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION['login']=$nombre;
            $arrResult["nombre"]=$nombre;
            //print_r($_SESSION);
            $stmt->close();
            $con->close();
        } else {
            $arrResult["error"]="Error preparando la consulta :".$con->error;     
        }

    } else {
        $arrResult["error"]= "Hay datos vacíos en el POST";
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_decode($arrResult);   
?>
```

---

### Javascript

Intenta tu petición Ajax de este modo (he omitido la llamada a `Limpiar()` porque no hace nada, si te interesa luego se la pones. Cuando estés aprendiendo evita usar funciones confusas en el código.

Lo fundamental es entender una cosa. El servidor responderá a Ajax con un objeto JSON que podrá tener, o bien una clave `error` o bien una clave `nombre`. En el `done` de la petición Ajax se verificará si el objeto tiene clave `error`, mostrando en ese caso un `alert` (eso lo puedes cambiar si quiere) y si no mostrará el valor de la clave `nombre`.

Me he centrado aquí en la petición Ajax, insértala en el contexto de tu código. Verás que uso `done` y `fail`. Eso es debido a que `success` y `error` son obsoletos desde jQuery 3.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:"../modelos/verificaloginestudiante.php",
    data:datos,
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: "false",
    beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#botonokestudiante').val("conectando...");
                }
});

request.done(function( data ) {
    $('#botonokestudiante').val("ingresar");
    /*Verificamos si no hubo errores en el servidor*/
    if( data.hasOwnProperty("error"){
        alert(data.error);
    }else{
        /*Si no hubo errores el JSON debe tener una clave nombre que se le mando desde PHP*/
        $('#idnombreusuario').val(data.nombre);
    }
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Hubo un fallo en la petición: " + textStatus );
});
```

Prueba así y si hay algún problema y dificultad lo dices en comentarios. Ten en cuenta que el código PHP también ha cambiado, para adaptarlo al tipo de dato que la petición Ajax espera.

Comment: ok gracias, pero ahora el login no se quiere ejecutar, bueno la cuestion es que se muestre el nombre del usuario en la pagina html, pero aparece el hola, todo el codigo esta bien, solo es ese detalle de que se muestre el nombre del usuario

Comment: Entendí que.querias mostrar el nombre del usuario. No sé qué quieres decir con que el login no se ejecuta.

Comment: disculpe el login SI SE EJECUTA, añadi una imagen mostrando donde debe aparecer el nombre del usuario. la parte de $_SESSION['login']='hola'; en ves de hola, debe aparecer el nombre del usuario que hizo el login, gracias por la bienvenida a stackoverflow

Comment: Pero yo puse un `print_r` de prueba, ¿se está mostrando eso o se muestra alguno de los mensajes de error  o el anterior mensaje de error?

Comment: el login funciona con el codigo original solo es que no se como hacer que muestre el usuario y no un hola

Comment: cuando copio su codigo el login no funciona, el login funciona solo con el codigo que mostre, solo pregunto como hacer para mostrar el nombre del usuario en ves de un hola, pero gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Yo he escrito una respuesta corrigiendo una serie de fallos en tu código muchos de ellos graves. Pero parece que no te interesa corregir nada de eso. ¿Si intentas mi código que muestra ya que dices que no funciona? Debe mostrar algún error.

Comment: bueno ya se que el codigo original tiene fallos pero es el unico que hace funcionar el login, he copiado otros y he visto videos pero nada, lo que pudiera funcionar seria alguna forma de mostrar el nombre del usuario y que el login funcionaria teniendo en cuenta solo el codigo original, por si acaso uso ajax para ejecutar el codigo del login

Comment: Si usas Ajax debiste decirlo desde el principio. Muestra el código Ajax entonces para ayudarte con eso. Es lógico que así no funcione, no sabía que estabas usando Ajax.

Comment: voy a editar la preguna para poner el codigo ajax

Comment: Debes confirmarme una cosa, ¿tu formulario se llama así realmente `formestudinte`? Parece un error ortográfico. ¿Podrías poner el HTML del formulario?

Comment: si se llama asi el formulario

Comment: que cuestion edite tu respuesta y puse el html del formulario

Comment: @olacris he editado la respuesta, adaptando el código PHP al tipo de petición que Ajax espera (un JSON). He incluido una propuesta de código para manejar la petición Ajax. Al principio es difícil entender cómo funciona Ajax, pero es muy simple: Aquí he indicado que quiero los datos en JSON, de ese modo busco la información por las claves de ese JSON, que serán en este caso sólo dos posibles: `nombre` o `error`. El código PHP devolverá ese JSON a Ajax y podrás mostrar los datos donde los necesites.

Comment: acabo de añadir el htlm completo del login

Comment: @olacris creo que el problema en este caso es que tienes por un lado un archivo que envía peticiones vía Ajax y luego en el archivo que recibe esas peticiones tienes una serie de cosas que no deberías tener. Por lo general los archivos que se usan en el parámetro `url` de las peticiones Ajax son archivos intermediarios que tienen como única función enviar y recibir datos entre el cliente y el servidor. Luego, los datos son mostrados en el mismo archivo que hizo la petición (o en otro archivo si se quiere). Deberías considerar una mejor organización de tu código, te evitará muchos problemas.

Comment: si tenez razon pero reescribir o hacer uno nuevo con los codigos de aqui  tomara tiempo, pero agradesco sus ayudas, y la tengo en cuenta cualquier cosa se estudiara, y ADEMAS ESTE CODIGO ES UN VERDADERO DESAFIO pero muy interesante si funcionaria

Answer (score 0):

mira, lo que dice @A.cedano tiene mucho que vale la pena tenerlo en cuenta, si tu dices que el codigo de el no te funciona y el tuyo si, entonces simplemente has lo que dice @A.cenado en su respuesta.
 
en tu variable  `$_SESSION['login']='hola';` cambia el 'hola' por lo que te retorna la variable `$resultpro` y haces referencia al campo `'nombre'` o como se llame en tu tabla es decir: `$_SESSION['login']= $resultpro['nombre'];`
De esa manera es posible que te quede como quieres.
Un saludo.

Comment: el campo nombre, hace referencia al campo del inpu text del formulario o al campo que esta en la base de datos?

Comment: ha igualmente un saludo!

Comment: Al campó de la base de datos

Comment: ahora surge un problema, cuando copio esto $_SESSION['login']= $resultpro['nombre'] no se inicia la sesion, pero cuando copio esto $_SESSION['login']='hola'; si inicia la sesion y me muestra el hola como  en la imagen de la pregunta

Comment: Pero te tira algún error?, puede ser que asi no se llame el campo de tu tabla o la otra es que intentes accediendo de la siguiente manera
$_SESSION['login'] = $resultpro->nombre;

Answer (score 0):

Si dices que el codigo esta bien pero te muestra un `Hola` en lugar del nombre, entonces ponle `$nombre`

```html
if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($qes)) {
            $resultpro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qes);
            echo 2;
            $_SESSION['login']='hola';
            // he aqui el error
            $_SESSION['login']=$nombre;
            // claro sera desde la DB
            $fila= mysql_fetch_array ($resultpro);
            $_SESSION['login']=$fila['nombre'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

pude variar la sintaxis pero es donde está tu duda

Comment: ok, ahora tengo una duda, $_SESSION['login']=$fila['esta valor se saca de la tabla de la base de datos?'];

Comment: asi es, `$_SESSION['login']=$fila['esta valor se saca de la tabla de la base de datos?']; ` es lo que te dá desde la DB, tu atributo o, si sabes las posiciones puedes usar `$fila[0],$fila[1]` o donde esté tu valor, caso de varios datos `$fila[0]['nombre'] o $fila[0][0]`, cogerá, el primer resultado

Comment: cuando copio esto:  $_SESSION['login']=$fila['nombre']; no se inicia la sesion, pero cuando copio esto  $_SESSION['login']='hola'; si se inicia la sesion que raro?

Comment: Ponle tu nombre en lugar de `hola` y funcionará, revisa tus resultados y trata de sacar los valores de ello, y averigua las formas de hacerlo.

Comment: jejejeje,buena idea, pero no, por que no todos los usuarios tienen el mismo nombre, lo que hare sera reescribir todo el proyecto o hacer uno nuevo he implementar todos los codigos de aqui a ver si funciona, espero que si, y ademas lo hare sin ajax sino con action en la etiqueta de form

Comment: pero sera para mas adelante, por lo tanto sigo con el actual